# ¿Cómo se realiza un getText en groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, bonita

buenos días el motivo de mi pregunto es como realizar un getText en groovy, ya que estoy utilizado bonitasoft(7.3) y maneja ese editor lo que quiero hacer es algo muy simple capturar los datos  de una caja de texto para para pasarlo a otra caja de texto pero al momento de realizar el getText no me funciona soy nuevo manejando el editor y no tengo muchas experiencia en editor  anexo el código

```js
import  java.lang.exception.*;
import java.lang.StackTraceElement;
try{
String  aux ="";
aux = nombre1.getText();
}catch(Exception  e )
{
 StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElement =e.getStackTraceElement(0);
   int n = stackTraceElement.length;
  aux = aux+ " -----";
  for (int i = 0 ;i<n;i++ )
  {
  aux = aux+ " "+stackTraceElement[i].getLineNumber()+">>"+stackTraceElement[i].getMethodName();
  }
}
return aux;
```

el nombre de la caja esta bien ya lo rectifiqué, pero no si si estoy haciendo  de manera adecuada en el  código me aparece una advertencia con relación al nombre de la caja de texto, pero no se si estoy llamado bien a la  caja de texto  gracias

es decir, obtengo:

nombre1 no se puede resolver. Puede provocar errores en tiempo de ejecución.

Pero, si en el código se pone $ name1, la advertencia se elimina pero el código no funciona. Creo que estoy llamando al cuadro de texto mal, pero no sé cómo llamarlo. He mirado la documentación de groovy  pero no puedo entender cómo realizar el procedimiento.